# Firebase realtime database onCall function does not return a response data object from remove() operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I use onCall to perform a remove operation from a realtime database. The operation is successfult but in the response I was expecting a data object, but only get null. I use onCall for other database operations e.g. update and get a response data object no problems.

**onCall implementation:**

```
exports.DeleteItemToShareRecord = functions.https.onCall((data,context)=>{
  const toDeleteRef = admin.database().ref("items_to_share/" + data["deleteID"]);
  toDeleteRef.remove().then(() => {        
      return { "message" : "item to share deleted" };
  });  
});
```

**Client Implementation:**

```
const deleteShareRecord = httpsCallable( this.functions, 'DeleteItemToShareRecord');
deleteShareRecord({"deleteID" : "" }).then((tresult)=>{ console.log("Delete item resposnse " , tresult); })
```

**Console log:**

Delete item response:

> {data: null}
>
> data: null

Is this intentional or a bug? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you add `return` before `toDeleteRef.remove()` and then try?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I needed to return the remove operation as pointed out by Dharmaraj

```
return toDeleteRef.remove().then(() => {        
  return { "data" : "new owner process complete" };
});
```